# How to compile C++ inside RapidsAI Docker Container

Tags: c++, docker, rapids

When inside the RapidsAI docker image with examples, how does one recompile the C++ code after modifying? I've tried running the build scripts from a terminal sessions inside Jupyter but it cannot find CMake.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to recompile the C++ code in a docker container you need to use the RAPIDS `Docker + Dev Env` container provided on https://rapids.ai/start.html.

The RAPIDS `Docker + Examples` container installs the RAPIDS libraries using conda install and does not contain the source C++ code or Cmake.

If you would like to continue to use the RAPIDS `Docker + Examples` container then I would suggest:

- First uninstall the existing library that you want to modify from the container.
- Then pull the [source code of the desired library](https://github.com/rapidsai) and make the
  required modifications.
- Once the above steps are done please follow
  the steps provided in the libraries github repo to build it from
  source.